# Custom JavaScript snippets for emmet (in Sublime Text 2)

Tags: javascript, customization, sublimetext2, code-snippets, emmet

I am trying to add some custom javascript snippets and abbreviations to the snippets.json file of Emmet, but I can't get it to work! (I am using Sublime Text 2.)

If I put this into the end of the settings.json

```
"javascript": {

    "abbreviations": {
        "while": "while(true)\n{\n\t\n}"
    },

    "snippets": {
        "asdf": "qwerty"
    }
}
```

nothing happens. (I set the syntax of the file to javascript obviously)

But if I replace 'javascript' with 'css':

```
"css": {

    "abbreviations": {
        "while": "while(true)\n{\n\t\n}"
    },

    "snippets": {
        "asdf": "qwerty"
    }
}
```

it correctly overwrites the built in CSS snippets, and works fine.
(I obviously set the syntax to css [otherwise it does NOT work])

What am I missing? according to this: http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/
I should be able to define snippets for custom languages this way.

Note: I have tried 'js' for the language name too.

Comment: What about the [Snippets page](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/) implies that you can add support for custom languages? I don't think Emmet is designed for Javascript; you'd probably be better off with something like [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) to power up your Javascript development. Still, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578259/how-to-make-zen-coding-support-javascript-files-in-sublime-text2) might help you (Emmet used to be called Zen Coding), though I don't know for certain.

Comment: Thank you, the question you linked is very helpful, but I decided to use Sublime's built-in Snippets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `js` as syntax name since Sublime Text defines JavaScript scope as `source.js`. In future, you should use `source.(SYNTAX_NAME)` part for syntax name.

And you shouldn’t use `abbreviations` section for snippets since abbreviations defines element blocks and should be written as HTML element. Use `snippets` section.

Note that in JS files in ST editor you have to use Ctrl+E to expand abbreviations since Tab key is disabled for this syntax.

And, as Protractor Ninja noted, it’s not a good idea to use Emmet snippets in editors that supports native ones.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! After researching some more I found this:
https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/207
[I think you answered that one too :)]
and decided to give the built-in snippet support of Sublime Text a try. (I wanted to use emmet originally because I wanted to store all my snippets at one place, and make sure nothing overlaps with the other one.) I find it to be a bit overcomplicated in my opinion [only one snippet per file, etc.], but I think I managed to get used to it, and it is pretty well-featured, so again, thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sergey.  I was trying to create a custom JavaScript snippet in my snippets.json file but it wasn't working.  After reading your answer I moved my code from the abbreviations section to the snippets section and now everything works great! (I can now insert a generic object literal into my code with a few keystrokes!)