# Emmet JS snippets in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, emmet

Has anyone ever succeeded in getting Emmet JS snippets to work in VS Code or even in Sublime?

The solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16943996/2012407 did not work for me.

These are my settings:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "vue-html": "html",
    "plaintext": "html"
},
```

This is my snippets.json:

```
{
    "javascript": {
        "abbreviations": {
            "cl": "console.log",
            "va": "var"
        },
        "snippets": {
            "cl": "console.log",
            "va": "var"
        }
    },
    "css": {
        "snippets": {
            "cb": "color: black",
            "bsd": "border: 1px solid ${1:red}"
        }
    }
}
```

There's no problem with CSS, SCSS, HTML, and all the rest - only JS. I've tried `abbreviations` or `snippets`, but the Emmet expansion puts HTML tags around what I write: `cl` becomes `<cl>` in Javascript & javascriptreact files.

I also tried `js` and `javascriptreact` in the snippets definition for the language with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

No need to add JS snippets in Emmet: the new concept of Emmet 2.0 (already available in VS Code; v2.0 in beta and not publicly released yet) works as autocomplete provider so you can simply use native VS Code snippets instead

Comment: I've seen this feature quickly in release notes. I was interested to know about emmet way so I can also use in Sublime. Can you briefly guide us with VS code built in way, how to set it up? so this question will be answered. cheers!

Comment: You should use the same native snippets approach in Sublime Text as well. Using Emmet as snippets provider for non-HTML and non-CSS syntaxes means you have to disable *all* native snippets provided by editor for given syntax and use Emmet instead. Also, ST currently uses old Emmet version which doesn’t use autocomplete so VSCode and ST are generally incompatible right now

Answer (score 2):

So I will put an example here for the built-in VS Code snippets, which are still not my favorite.

Open the command prompt with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and type `user snippets`. There is already an example in there. Uncomment it, save, and you can use it straight away by typing the prefix.

> I had to create the same snippet file named `javascriptreact.json` as well for it to work in most of my JS files - Javascript React (babel)

Ex:

```
{
    "Test": {
        "prefix": "ts",
        "body": [
            "console.log('test')",
            "$1"
        ],
        "description": "Prints test"
    }
}
```

Now I have Emmet mapped to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and having the built-in snippets limited to the intellisense is not great. I'd like a key binding like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, and I am a big fan of Emmet.

**I am still keen on having it working with Emmet using the same key binding if anyone knows.**